# Delphi XML order

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, rad-studio

I am having trouble creating XML's with the right complextype and element order within my Delphi project in Rad Studio 2007.
I have auto generated an interface class from the XSD. But in comparison to C# for instance I cannot set an order to the elements.
When I create the XML document the complextypes/elements are set in the order of which they are set from code.
Which gives me an incorrect XML, because of the other pary forcing the XSD order.

Is there a way to enforce an order in the creation of the XML in Delphi using the Delphi XML IXMLDocument/IXMLNode/IXMLNodeCollection classes or maybe within the interface classes? Or must this be done mannually?

Comment: It must be done manually.  Elements appear in the order in which they are created.

Comment: @RemyLebeau so there are also no other libraries/components that support this?

Comment: hard to answer without seeing your actual code and the XML that is not working for you

Comment: You could re-order them using XSL after the XML document has been created.